# Trying to perform a a linq query that joins two tables, has a where clause, and groups the results

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am sure it is a simple, but I can't quite get it to work. This is the SQL query I am using as my reference. I want to make this same thing happen with LINQ.

SQL:

```
select
schedulegroupslist.Schedule_Group_Key,
schedulegroupslist.Group_Name
from schedulegroupslist
inner join schedules on schedules.schedule_group_key = schedulegroupslist.Schedule_Group_Key
where schedules.Active = 1
and schedulegroupslist.Schedule_Count > 0
and schedulegroupslist.Active = 1
group by schedulegroupslist.Schedule_Group_Key
,schedulegroupslist.Group_Name
```

Here is the linq I thought would do the trick, but I a getting a null reference exception on group schedules line.

LINQ:

```
var included = from g in allGroups
           join s in allSchedules 
           on g.ScheduleGroupKey equals s.GroupKey into sg
           from schedules in sg.Where(s => s.Active == true 
                                           && g.ScheduleCount > 0 
                                           && g.Active == true).DefaultIfEmpty()
           group schedules by 
                    new { schedules.Key, schedules.ScheduleGroupName } 
                    into schedulesgroup
           select new { GroupName = schedulesgroup.Key.ScheduleGroupName,
                        ScheduleGroupKey = schedulesgroup.Key.Key };
```

Not that fluent with linq, so maybe someone can show me a better way to accomplish what I am doing?

Comment: This is a really good cheat-sheet: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var included = from g in allGroups
               join s in allSchedules on g.ScheduleGroupKey equals s.GroupKey
               where s.Active && g.ScheduleCount > 0 && g.Active
               group s by new { s.Key, s.ScheduleGroupName } into grp
               select new
               {
                   ScheduleGroupKey = grp.Key.Key,
                   GroupName = grp.Key.ScheduleGroupName,
               };
```

I think grouping is useless in this case so this might work even better:

```
var included = from g in allGroups
               join s in allSchedules on g.ScheduleGroupKey equals s.GroupKey
               where s.Active && g.ScheduleCount > 0 && g.Active
               select new
               {
                   ScheduleGroupKey = s.Key,
                   GroupName = s.ScheduleGroupName,
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var included = from g in allGroups
           join s in allSchedules on g.ScheduleGroupKey equals s.GroupKey
           where s.Active == true 
                 && g.ScheduleCount > 0 
                 && g.Active == true
           group g by new { g.ScheduleGroupKey, g.ScheduleGroupName } into gr
           select new 
           {
               gr.Key.ScheduleGroupKey,
               gr.Key.ScheduleGroupName
           }
```